# What happened to Karl Franz?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, end-of-times

I've just finished reading [The Fall of Altdorf](http://www.blacklibrary.com/all-products/the-fall-of-altdorf-ebook.html), at the end Karl Franz.

> dies

However it's strongly implied that something else happens. My impression is that

> he's resurrected as the first of the Stormcast Eternals

But as the story is told from the perspective of the participating characters it's extremely vague. What actually happens to Karl Franz?

Comment: As a rule of the thumb, don't bother trying to compare lore between Warhammer Fantasy and Age of Sigmar. They are barely related, in the same way that a dog and a lion are vaguely related.

Comment: @Theik Most of the _old_ gods and characters are in AOS in some form, as are most the the _old_ races. We just don't know who's who at the moment. I think it's a horrible mess and it's completely ruined Warhammer Fantasy for me forever (they killed Brunner), but there you go.

Comment: @Daft Considering only Sigmar seems to be aware of things that previously happened, they are basically just new characters with the same name and looks. Their previous history is useless.

Comment: @Theik a lot of them have flashbacks or feel old emotions in certain situations. There's scope to build on their previous lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole Stromcast Eternal thing doesn't start for many thousands of years after The End Times. As it stands we don't know who any of them are, BL has not explained that yet.

They've pretty much said that any hero or villain dead or alive at any point throughout Warhammer Fantasy could potentially be a Stormcast Eternal, as Sigmar Heldenhammer gathered the strongest souls he could from thoughout time after The End Times to build his new army.

What happens to Karl Franz in Altdorf is:

*The Lord of The End Times spoiler alert*

> his body is actually possessed by a shard of Sigmar Heldenhammer. Sigmar binds the Wind of Heaven to Franz' body, and in doing so possesses his dead body and turns him into an incarnate. This becomes clear and is explained in [The Lord of The End Times](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Warhammer/the-lord-of-the-end-times-ebook.html).

Comment: Guess I need to finish the series!

Comment: @Liath I almost asked this exact question myself after I read Fall of Altdorf. And if you did read that spoiler, don't worry too much, it's made apparent pretty early in Lord of The End Times.